# Monit: How to exec when timeout/unmonitor?

Tags: monit

How to execute a script as last step, when monit timeout a service?

My config looks like this:

```
check process php5-fpm with pidfile /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
    start program = "/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm start"
    stop program  = "/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm stop"
    if failed unixsocket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock then restart
    if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

There is an option to send an email on timeout like this

```
alert address@hostname only on { timeout }
```

but how to execute a script, to e.g. send a SMS, on timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You can just exec any executable in an error state with

```
if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then exec "/usr/sbin/apacheSmsRestart"
```

and `/usr/sbin/apacheSmsRestart` beeing (+`chmod +x /usr/sbin/apacheSmsRestart`)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Trigger SMS with... literally anything. ;)
curl 'https://smsgateway.example.com/to/1337421337/text/hello+world'

# Do restart
/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm restart

# Exit with last call's exit code
exit $?
```